# Need to scan WEB-INF/lib/xxx-ejb.jar for Type and Method annotations

Tags: annotations, java-ee-6, reflections

I want to do the following using Google Reflections:

1. Scan only WEB-INF/lib/Patrac-ejb.jar
2. Scan only the package com.patrac and all of its sub-packages.
3. Scan for only type- and method annotations.

The following configuration seems to work fine but I don't have any experience with Google Reflections.

```
Reflections reflections = new Reflections(
    new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder().include("Patrac-ejb.jar").include(FilterBuilder.prefix("com.patrac")))
        .setScanners(new MethodAnnotationsScanner(), new TypeAnnotationsScanner())
        .setUrls(ClasspathHelper.forWebInfLib(servletContext))
);
```

It appears to be working.  I want to make sure it's not scanning all the other JARs in WEB-INF/lib.  Is there an easy way to discover what JARs are being matched by the filter inputs in the configuration?  Any advice about my approach would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked:

```
   //   Get the URL for Patrac-ejb.jar:
   Set<URL> urls = ClasspathHelper.forWebInfLib(webUtil.getServletContext());
   URL patracJarUrl = null;
   for(URL url : urls)
   {
       if(url.getFile().endsWith("Patrac-ejb.jar"))
       {
           patracJarUrl = url;
           break;
       }
   }
   if(null == patracJarUrl)
   {
       throw new IllegalStateException("Patrac-ejb.jar not found.");
   }

   //   Add the Patrac-ejb.jar URL to the configuration.
   Configuration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
       .filterInputsBy(new FilterBuilder()
                       .include(FilterBuilder.prefix("com.patrac")))
       .setScanners(new MethodAnnotationsScanner(), new TypeAnnotationsScanner())
       .setUrls(patracJarUrl);
```